# Python BeautifulSoup finding table and parsing it

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

This one is an odd one I ran this code in the morning and it worked just fine on the html from page. Now when I run it the tables variable comes back 0 items so the for loop never happens and no data is collected or data frame created

```py
def parseForclosure(pagesource):
    data = []
    soup = BeautifulSoup(pagesource,'html.parser')
    tables = soup.find_all('table', attrs={'class':'ad_tab'})
    print(len(tables))
    df2 = pd.DataFrame()
    for i in range(len(tables)):
        print(i)
        table_body = tables[i].find('tbody')

        rows = table_body.find_all('tr')
        for row in rows:
            cols = row.find_all('td')
            cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
            data.append([ele for ele in cols if ele])

        data2 ={'AuctionType': [data[0]] ,
                'CaseNo': [data[1]],
                'FinalJudgmentAmount': [data[2]],
                'ParcelID': [data[3]],
                'PropertyAddress1': [data[4]],
                'PropertyAddress2': [data[5]],
                'AssessedValue': [data[6]],
                'PlaintiffMaxBid': [data[7]]}

        df = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=['AuctionType','CaseNo','FinalJudgmentAmount','ParcelID','PropertyAddress1','PropertyAddress2','AssessedValue','PlaintiffMaxBid'] )
        df2 = df2.append(df)
    print(df)
    return(df2)
```

Here is the call

```
 df = parseForclosure(source)
```

Here is a snippet of what the html look like

```
<table class="ad_tab" tabindex="0"><tbody><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Auction Type:</th><td class="AD_DTA">FORECLOSURE</td></tr><tr><th aria-label="Case Number" class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Case #:</th><td class="AD_DTA"><a href="/index.cfm?zaction=auction&amp;zmethod=details&amp;AID=103757&amp;bypassPage=1">07009032CA01</a></td></tr><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Final Judgment Amount:</th><td class="AD_DTA">$323,248.61</td></tr><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Parcel ID:</th><td class="AD_DTA">30-6901-001-2470</td></tr><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Property Address:</th><td class="AD_DTA">12260 SW 191 ST</td></tr><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row"></th><td class="AD_DTA">MIAMI, FL- 33177</td></tr> <tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Assessed Value:</th><td class="AD_DTA">$184,791.00</td></tr><tr><th class="AD_LBL" scope="row">Plaintiff Max Bid:</th><td class="AD_DTA ASTAT_MSGPB">Hidden</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

You can see sample of all the tables in the link below.

https://projectcodesamples.s3.amazonaws.com/AuctionSample.html

My objective is place data points into a dataframe

Sample file with missing data points:

[Sample_Missing_data_points](https://projectcodesamples.s3.amazonaws.com/shortFile.html)

This is a sample file with all datapoints

[Sample_file_with_no_missing_data_points](https://projectcodesamples.s3.amazonaws.com/CompleteFile.html)

Ideally I should be able to extract from both without the dataframe size changing

Comment: Is it possible the site is blocking you because of scraping behavior?  Are you checking for an error code from the request before trying to parse it?

Comment: hum... ok how can i verify your claim. Like I said I pulled it before. Suddenly code not working seems odd. Any suggestions

Comment: Well, as I said, you need to check the error code from the request.  You should probably debug print the `pagesource` to make sure it looks like what you think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say that you have three HTML files with the data you provided since you first posted your question:

- Source.html
- Source2.html
- Source3.html

I have used this updated code to combine all the data in one dataframe:

```py
import io
import csv

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

input_files_names = [
    'Source.html',
    'Source2.html',
    'Source3.html'
]
def setup_dataframes(files_names):
    for current_file_name in files_names:
        with open(current_file_name) as source_file:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(source_file, 'html.parser')

        field_labels = {
            'AuctionType': 'Auction Type:',
            'CaseNo': 'Case #:',
            'JudgementAmount': 'Final Judgment Amount:',
            'ParcelID': 'Parcel ID:',
            'AssessedValue': 'Assessed Value:',
            'PlaintiffMaxBid': "Plaintiff Max Bid:"
        }

        column_names = (
            'AuctionType', 
            'CaseNo', 
            'JudgementAmount', 
            'ParcelID', 
            'PropertyAddress1', 
            'PropertyAddress2',
            'AssessedValue',
            'PlaintiffMaxBid'
        )

        def extract_data(soup):
            for current_table in soup.find_all('table', class_='ad_tab'):
                current_auction = {}
                for (current_field, current_labal) in field_labels.items():
                    current_field_cell = current_table.tbody.find('th', string=current_labal)
                    if current_field_cell is not None:
                        current_data_cell = current_field_cell.next_sibling
                        current_auction[current_field] = current_data_cell.get_text()
                
                address_row = current_table.tbody.find('th', string='Property Address:')
                if address_row is not None:
                    current_auction['PropertyAddress1'] = address_row.find_next_sibling('td').get_text()
                
                    address2_row = address_row.parent.next_sibling.td
                    if address2_row is not None:
                        current_auction['PropertyAddress2'] = address2_row.get_text()

                yield tuple(current_auction.get(current_field, '') for current_field in column_names)

        with io.StringIO() as intermediate_data:
            intermediate_csv = csv.writer(intermediate_data)
            intermediate_csv.writerows(extract_data(soup))
            intermediate_data.seek(0, 0)
            df = pd.read_csv(intermediate_data, header=None, names=column_names)

        yield df

df_composite = pd.concat(setup_dataframes(input_files_names), ignore_index=True)
print(df_composite)
```

What has been done here is:

- Extracting the text from the source HTML file by finding each file before creating a output row
- Creating a temporary, in memory, CSV file using [io.StringIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) and  the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)
- Creating a Pandas dataframe from that CSV file using [pd.read_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/io.html#csv-text-files)

If you are processing a lot of data you may consider writing to a real file instead instead of using an in-memory file.

Comment: Thanks EvensF, Yes your correct as a file your code works. I tried to use your code to pull from the web page and it would come up blank. the soup variable has the html data though thats why I dont understand why it just wont pull? I understand your point about the site not letting me but I feel if that were the case the soup variable would be empty.

Comment: Like @Tim Roberts said, maybe it's something outside of the code you presented that is the problem. Could you provide an [example]? If you use [requests module](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), what is the response you receive?

Comment: Yes, issue was outside. This code did work but it has issues while parsing data it is failing with older data because its expecting some of the fields that didnt exists at that time.  Any way to account for missing columns in the data.

Comment: Can you provide an example of this type of HTML file with missing information?

Comment: EvensF there are 2 new links now in questions to samples that have all data points and another with no missing data points